# How to minimize apps/games without restart?

Tags: applications

Recently i playing a games called Clash of kings.
But when i minimize this game and opean again.
This game is automatically restart.
So, Is there any way to minimize this game and open again without restart?
note:i face the same problem in clash of clans.

Answer (score 1):

If the app is not coded strangely then this should happen automatically.  (Otherwise, you'll need to contact the developers.)

However, it seems likely that your device is running out of free RAM and is either terminating the app or telling it to release memory.  You can try running fewer apps/services at the same and see if it helps; otherwise, you'll need a device with more RAM.

One more option is (if you have a rooted device) to convert the app into a System app.  They are given higher priority and not killed as frequently; I just did this with tTorrent last night because it was being instantly killed in the background, and now it's working fine.

Comment: But i see not all apps or games restart.
Is there any apps available those solve this problem?

Comment: @deven due to how Android is developed (having only 1 active `Activity`), I don't think there's a way to intercept and replace an application lifecycle when the developer decides to do restart it. You don't know what happens, and you also don't know if preventing it to restart will break the app or not (let's say for example, the network session you currently use in the game is discarded when you minimize).

Comment: @deven It's probably the apps that use less memory which are not restarting.  I've also added one more solution to my answer.